# Display data from text file in html using httpclient

Tags: node.js, angular, file, http, get

I am working on an angular project. I have a text file which that is red using node js. The content is then stored in a url. I need to apply an http get method to get the data from the server and display it on the client side.
I tried the following code but when I hit the button I don't get the file data displayed. What is the problem?

src/app/file.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getFile() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/hello');
    }
}
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<p>
    <button (click)="getFile()">get data</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems. First, you're not subscribing to the Observable, so nothing is going to happen. Second, you also need to handle the Observable, you're not. Third, you have not defined a place to inject the data once received.

```
...

    @Injectable()
    export class ConfigService {
        data = {};

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

        getFile() {
            this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/hello').subscribe(result => {
               this.data = result });
        }

    }
```

then you need somewhere to display it,

```
<p>
    <button (click)="getFile()">get data</button>
    <div *ngIf="data">{{ data }}</div>
</p>
```

Comment: JDunken I tried your code but I got two problems. The first one is that I can't initialise the variable data outside of the Class. And secondly I don't get any data displayed in the front page of my application.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, that should have been inside the class. Edited answer.

Comment: Even when I moved data inside the class, I still don't get any data displayed. I don't know if something is missing in the code.

Comment: If you have a simple example that can help me on stackblitz or any other online editor please send it. Thank you.

Comment: I can't use stackblitz or similar at work due to security settings. If you have one let me know and I can take a look later.